# how to pay an apple developer account without two-factor authentication?

Tags: ios

I want to pay an account developer apple.  when I turn to pay a message appears: "Two-factor authentication must be turned on for your Apple ID". I don't have apple devices. How to pay an apple developer account without two-factor authentication?

[message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4R66T.jpg)

Comment: As the message states, you can use two factor authentication using a text message even without an Apple device.

Comment: thanks. but I think it can be done for **two-step** authentication apple, but it cannot be done for **two-factor** authentication

Comment: Yes, you need to enrol your Apple ID for two step authentication

Comment: But I need **two factor** authentication. https://i.stack.imgur.com/4R66T.jpg 
Can I pay a developer account with **two-step** authentication?
Apple says there is a difference between these two authentications...

Comment: The screen shot you posted mentions text message so I would assume you cab use two step, but I don’t know for sure since I use two factor